# MetaMask cannot send transaction on local network

Tags: metamask, geth-debugging

I'm running Geth in dev mode locally, like this:

```
geth --ipcpath test-chain-directory/geth.ipc --datadir test-chain-directory --dev --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" console
```

I can send a transaction from the console, and it works, but when I connect MetaMask to http://localhost:8545, sending a transaction from one account to another fails.

I've made sure to run `miner.start()` before sending the transaction, but it fails in MetaMask with the following error:

```
Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":3105471441522,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["0x...."],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} Error: invalid sender
```

The account I'm sending from was one I created via the console, and funded with Eth, before importing into MetaMask, and MetaMask show's balance correctly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comment by skozin and the files in the repo he provided help me to fix the problem:

https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/2015#issuecomment-345405915

Basically, make sure to set in the genesis.conf :

eip155Block:0 and chainId equals to the networkId (used with geth)

Comment: That seems to work - I was using Geth with the 'dev' flag to avoid needing a genesis block and a DAG etc.

Answer (score 1):

- Step First:
  This comment by skozin and the files in the repo he provided help me to fix the 
  problem:

  https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/2015#issuecomment-345405915

  Basically, make sure to set in the genesis.conf :

  eip155Block:0 and chainId equals to the networkId (used with geth)
- Step Second:
  if you had fixed the problem mentioned above (the problem mentioned in Step First), then it Most likely is you start local network in a wrong way like:

```
geth --ipcpath test-chain-directory/geth.ipc --datadir test-chain-directory --dev --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" console
```

you should cut the `--dev` off! Because using Geth with the 'dev' flag to avoid needing a genesis block and a DAG, you should start your local network Like below:

```
geth --ipcpath test-chain-directory/geth.ipc --datadir test-chain-directory --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*"
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In metamask update your chainID to the private network ID. It worked for me