# MetaMask won't send txs on local dev chain

Tags: metamask, ganache, dev-chain, etherlime

I'm running a local dev chain for development using [Etherlime](https://github.com/LimeChain/etherlime). When trying to interact with the chain using MetaMask, I get the following error:

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":2084025564758,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["0xf88902847735940082b6ae94254d97074fb0053437dffadd6bac5c3af19781a580a47048027500000000000000000000000056a32fff5e5a8b40d6a21538579fb8922df5258c820a95a0afdd402623efd96be41e863da2c38130f9d2092ea66b8a8aa2dd4ecf7864da3da024b3f0aad9be55b31b6dc035f0c3a9f22a8b2f7e2331668214abe9b1cde6239f"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} [object Object] 
Object { code: -32603, message: "Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {\"id\":2084025564758,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"params\":[\"0xf88902847735940082b6ae94254d97074fb0053437dffadd6bac5c3af19781a580a47048027500000000000000000000000056a32fff5e5a8b40d6a21538579fb8922df5258c820a95a0afdd402623efd96be41e863da2c38130f9d2092ea66b8a8aa2dd4ecf7864da3da024b3f0aad9be55b31b6dc035f0c3a9f22a8b2f7e2331668214abe9b1cde6239f\"],\"method\":\"eth_sendRawTransaction\"} [object Object]", stack: "Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {\"id\":2084025564758,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"params\":[\"0xf88902847735940082b6ae94254d97074fb0053437dffadd6bac5c3af19781a580a47048027500000000000000000000000056a32fff5e5a8b40d6a21538579fb8922df5258c820a95a0afdd402623efd96be41e863da2c38130f9d2092ea66b8a8aa2dd4ecf7864da3da024b3f0aad9be55b31b6dc035f0c3a9f22a8b2f7e2331668214abe9b1cde6239f\"],\"method\":\"eth_sendRawTransaction\"} [object Object]" }
```

I see a similar issue [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/36133/27270), there putting `eip155:0` in the `genesis.conf` was supposed to solve the problem, but there doesn't seem to be any genesis file in dev chains, at least as far as I can tell. (I did a `git grep` on my project, and also searched Etherlime's GitHub repo.) If that's the case, this would need a different solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to reset Metamask. Also, your private blockchain should not  have a networkId different from the chainId when dealing with Metamask.

Comment: can you explain both of these points a bit more @clement ? When you say to 'reset' MetaMask, do you mean a full reinstall and mnemonic import? Also, where would I find the chain and network ids? (to be clear, anywhere that I know of they're set to the same value)

Comment: In the Metamask advanced parameters you can reset your account, it will only clear all of your transactions history. It is sometimes necessary when you work on different chains because it happens Metamask confuses the nonces. For the chainId, it should be specified in the genesis file.

Comment: do dev chains even have genesis files? If they do, do you know where I could find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up moving to a testnet to solve this, but the general consensus seems to be that this is caused by the [nonce](https://support.mycrypto.com/general-knowledge/ethereum-blockchain/what-is-nonce) getting messed up by stopping and restarting dev chains.

The fix is to reset the tx history in MetaMask. This can be done by going to settings (you can find that menu by clicking on the generated circle art thing for your account in the upper right hand corner, selecting 'Advanced' from the menu, and then doing an account reset. (As stated clearly inside the MetaMask app, this should not reset your balance nor make you reenter your seed.)

[image: MetaMask account reset screens]
(The picture doesn't reflect the exact same UI as MetaMask, at least not my version, but should be close enough to be helpful.)

Here's MetaMask's page on account resets: https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015488891-Resetting-an-Account

Again, I didn't actually try this, but have heard it enough times that I figured I should leave it here in case someone else experiences the same issue.